# Scala reflection: knownDirectSubclasses only works for sealed traits?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Given  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165932/macros-knowndirectsubclasses-broken-with-nested-type) and [SI-7046](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7046), this isn't at all what I expected.

`scalac test.scala && scala Test` in Scala 2.11.6 on the following prints an empty `Set()`:

```
trait Foo
case class Bar() extends Foo
case class Baz() extends Foo

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
    println( typeOf[Foo].typeSymbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses )
  }
}
```

However, if I change `trait Foo` to `sealed trait Foo`, it prints `Set(class Bar, class Baz)` as expected.

What's going on here?

Comment: did you try actually using/referencing Bar and Baz? The JVM dynamically loads classes using a classloader (duh). It might have different loading rules for seemingly unrelated classes that just extend something but be more exhaustive on sealed traits.

Comment: Good question! I checked and adding a declaration + println for Baz() and Bar() doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

look the doc

```
/** If this is a sealed class, its known direct subclasses.
 *  Otherwise, the empty set.
 *
 *  @group Class
 */
def knownDirectSubclasses: Set[Symbol]
```