# Recursively obtain subclass(es) of a class

Tags: scala, class, reflection, subclass

Main Question: How can you print all the subclasses (recursively) of a class in Scala?

Context:

I am using the CDE library (https://github.com/chipsalliance/cde) that is used in a variety of downstream projects to parameterize classes. As a result of using the library, a large amount of case classes are created extending a class called `Config` (across multiple Scala files), like so:

```scala
class Cfg0 extends Config(...)

class Cfg1 extends Cfg0

class Cfg2 extends Cfg1
```

Our users normally manually call out the "Config" object names in Makefiles, etc and I would like to print the names of all the classes so that these classes are easier to discover (instead of grepping).

Definition of `Config` class: https://github.com/chipsalliance/cde/blob/384c06b8d45c8184ca2f3fba2f8e78f79d2c1b51/cde/src/chipsalliance/rocketchip/config.scala#L151

I've looked at:

[How do I use Scala reflection to find all subclasses of a trait (without using third-party tools)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834824/how-do-i-use-scala-reflection-to-find-all-subclasses-of-a-trait-without-using-t)
https://gist.github.com/longshorej/1a0a2cf50de8e6ff101c

But they looked like they were oriented around case classes/traits.

Comment: The answer by Dmytro Mitin is NOT "oriented around case classes/traits" and it lists other answers for JVM in general: runtime reflection scanning whole classpath for anything that has specified class/interface as an ancestor. For instance, the first link literally provides a code for `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` from Spring Framework.

Comment: Nothing special about traits and case classes compared to other types of classes in this respect. The question you referenced has the exact answer you are looking for.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I guess OP referred to the 2nd part of that my answer. It's indeed oriented around case classes/sealed trait (class).

Comment: @Dima If a trait or class is not sealed, `knownDirectSubclasses` stops to work. If a hierarchy is not a sealed trait and case classes, `Generic`/`LabelledGeneric` stops to work.

Comment: @DmytroMitin yes, of course. _sealed_ is a special case, which is also expressly explained in your answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly updated my answer at [How do I use Scala reflection to find all subclasses of a trait (without using third-party tools)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834824/how-do-i-use-scala-reflection-to-find-all-subclasses-of-a-trait-without-using-t)

Out of the options listed there, for example **at runtime** you can use classpath scanners like [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph), [Burningwave](https://www.burningwave.org/), ...

```
// libraryDependencies += "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.10.2"
import org.reflections.Reflections
import org.reflections.scanners.Scanners.SubTypes
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

val reflections = new Reflections()
reflections.get(SubTypes.of(classOf[Config]).asClass()).asScala
// Set(class Cfg0, class Cfg1, class Cfg2)
```

---

Or **at compile time** you can try [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) and [macro-based](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html) type class `KnownSubclasses` from [Shapeless - How to derive LabelledGeneric for Coproduct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75544693/shapeless-how-to-derive-labelledgeneric-for-coproduct) (traversing ASTs in all compilation units of a current compiler run, not using `scala-reflect` `.knownDirectSubclasses`)

```
// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
import shapeless.{Coproduct, HList, Poly0, Poly1, Typeable}
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.ToHList
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{FillWith, Mapper, ToList}

object typeablePoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[A](implicit typeable: Typeable[A]): Case.Aux[A, String] =
    at(_ => typeable.describe)
}

object nullPoly extends Poly0 {
  implicit def cse[A]: Case0[A] = at(null.asInstanceOf[A])
}

def getSubclasses[A] = new PartiallyAppliedGetSubclasses[A]

class PartiallyAppliedGetSubclasses[A] {
  def apply[C <: Coproduct, L <: HList, L1 <: HList]()(implicit
    knownSubclasses: KnownSubclasses.Aux[A, C],
    toHList: ToHList.Aux[C, L],
    mapper: Mapper.Aux[typeablePoly.type, L, L1],
    fillWith: FillWith[nullPoly.type, L],
    toList: ToList[L1, String]
  ): List[String] =
    toList(mapper(fillWith()))
}

getSubclasses[Config]()
// List(Cfg0, Cfg1, Cfg2)
```

**For both above options it's irrelevant whether traits/classes are sealed or not, whether classes are case classes or not.**